# Find $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 1+\alpha+x-\sqrt{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2+2(x-\alpha)+1} $ with $\alpha>0$

Tags: analysis, limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit, numerically it should go to zero, but I'm not sure how to show this analytically, any help would be appreciated! If I work it out I'll post an update!

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}
\left[
1+\alpha+x-\sqrt{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2+2(x-\alpha)+1}
\right]
$$

where $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$\sqrt{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2+2(x-\alpha)+1}=\left(\alpha+x\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{2(x-\alpha)+1 }{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2}}$$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem $$\sqrt{1+\frac{2(x-\alpha)+1 }{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2} }=1+\frac 12 \frac{2(x-\alpha)+1 }{\left(\alpha+x\right)^2}+\cdots$$

Just continue.

Comment: Ah jeez, that's extremely obvious now, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: multiply denominator and numerator by $$1+\alpha+x+\sqrt{(\alpha+x)^2+2(x-\alpha)+1}$$ (the denominator is $1$)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)